# Load require file and do not show the lines displayed(echo) in file

Tags: php, echo, require

I have a PHP file that echo (displays) a array.
I cannot clone this file.
Now I want to use this array in another script, so I require_once it.
Though now it also echo (displays) the array which i don't want.

Is there a way to load in the array but not echo the data?

Comment: Whats with: Don't "echo" it within the script?

Comment: What do you mean 'cannot clone'?

Comment: I cannot simply duplicate the script containing the array and delete the echo. So I need to require the script that has the echo.

Comment: It would be better for you to add sample codes @Roy van Zanten

Comment: Better change the script to not echo but to return it. If you retrieve an Array in a string format there's no good way to convert it back to Array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [ob_start()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [ob_end_clean()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) to block whole output of 'required' script.
In example code below `first.php` 'requires' `second.php`, and in `second.php` is declared and printed an array `$array`.

Since all output of `second.php` is being captured into memory buffer, after executing `first.php` `$array` will be printed only once in the output.

**first.php**

```
<?php
ob_start();
require_once 'second.php';
ob_end_clean();
print_r($array);
?>
```

**second.php**

```
<?php
$array = array( 'a', 'b', 'c');
print_r($array);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the [Output Control Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php)